# Deconstruct a C++ code block from a novice perspective

Tags: c++

I am *very* new to C++ and I am trying to deconstruct someone's code, and I am not quite sure what to Google for, hence I am just going to ask here. This is a second attempt at a question I asked earlier which was poorly posed. Should this one not measure up, please let me know and I shall try to rectify.

Here is a structurally identical MWE, of the piece of code I am trying to understand.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int square(int x){
    // Function that squares without using *
    int result = 0;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < x; ++counter){ 
        result += x;
    }
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    int const D = 4;
    int myArray[D] = {};    // all elements 0 in C++
    char colour[D] = {'c','o','e','g'};   // Initialize String Array
    int AEST = 5; // Initialise AEST
    for (int d =0; d<D; d++){
        if (colour[d]!='c' && colour[d]!='o'){
             double aux= square (d);
             if (aux!=0){
                myArray[d]=aux;
             }else{ 
                return AEST; 
             }
         }
    }
    // Lets see what we achieved.
    for (int d =0; d<D; d++){ 
        cout << myArray[d];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now then, lets crack on with some questions.

Precisely what I do not fully understand is this block:

```
             }else{ 
                return AEST; 
             }
```

Please not, `AEST` is not an error code, it is a numerical value that the code calculates. I have only initialized it here for the purpose of this MWE, but in actuality, it is calculated earlier on in the original code block.

My question is as follows:

The `if` statement is only true if the colours are not `c` or `o` and in which case we square `d`. In the MWE we square `d` twice. Hence, is the code then saying that we break out of the loop (with `return AEST`) IF we stumble upon a colour that is not `c` or `o`? But if we do break out of the loop under these conditions, why must we return `AEST`? It is already initialised `AEST=5` earlier on, and nothing we do inside this loop will affect it (remember this block is structurally identical to what I am trying to understand, but obviously not fully identical). This is why I do not understand the `else` bit.

Again, if there is not enough information, please let me know.

Comment: Ah. Dirty code problem then. Returning from `main()` in C++ finishes the program with the error code from `return` statement. It seems that `AEST` is some sort of badly-documented error code (what does it mean? What happened that we need to close program?). Note that there is `return 0;` in the end, with similar puprose, but signalling success.

Comment: as @Vulpex said it seems like a sort of error code, because the reaturn statement exit from the main(), not the loop. If it would exit from loop it would used `break` statement. BTW this not look at good code so does not make programming assumption about the Language based on this code.

Comment: @Moia sorry do you mean to say from "BTW this not look at good code so does not make programming assumption" that the original code is not good?

Comment: I think I saw somewhere that the return value from the `main` function should be between 0 and 255.

Comment: @Astrid Does your actual code have the `return AEST;` in the `main()` function, or in some other function? That's an important distinction to make. Returning from `main` terminates the program, returning from any other function doesn't.

Comment: @Astrid Exactly. But it looks like an example code more than a real one (and it resemble too much at a C with cout more than C++)

Comment: @acraig5075 that `return` statement sits inside an identical `if` statement like the one in the MWE, which sits inside the `main()` function in the original code. Hence, by construction, my MWE is identical. Their main is not called `main()` though -- though I do not think that makes a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return AEST` part in question exits the `main()` function. That means the program exits in state 5.

This is done to have some sort of error code detection. For example. If you have various things that can go wrong, you try to retun those with specific codes so you can look up and identify where the problem occured.

It is common to `return 0` if everything is fine.